# Force 9patch Image to fit width, with paddings

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am using 9patch image for my `ListView` item xml file.

However, the image background doesn't seem to fit layout width.

Item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/lvbg" >

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDate"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#31B6E7" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

List.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm acheiving

[image]

What I need :

[image]

This is my 9patch image

[image]

Is it possible to force the textview inside, at the same time, the 9patch image is able to fill the screen width with a few dp padding at the sides.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to how you inflate the layout. You should do something like following in your getView() methode (in your adapter):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
        LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = Inflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
```

Now the important part is that you use the `parent` and you set it to not being attached (`false`). By doing this Android can measure the component properly and thereby giving it the right dimensions.